# Pycharm: Run manage task won't work if path contains space

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm running Pycharm 2.6.3 with python 2.7 and django 1.5.1. When I try to run django's manage.py task from Pycharm (Tools / Run manage.py task), syncdb, for instance, I get the following:

```
bash -cl "/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/paulo/bin/pycharm-2.6.3/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py syncdb /home/paulo/Projetos/repo2/Paulo Brito/phl"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/paulo/bin/pycharm-2.6.3/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 170, in run_module
    mod_name, loader, code, fname = _get_module_details(mod_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 103, in _get_module_details
    raise ImportError("No module named %s" % mod_name)
ImportError: No module named manage

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If I run the first line on the console passing project path between single quotes, it runs without problems, like this:

```
bash -cl "/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/paulo/bin/pycharm-2.6.3/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py syncdb '/home/paulo/Projetos/repo2/Paulo Brito/phl'"
```

I tried to format the path like that in project settings / django support, but Pycharm won't recognize the path.

How can I work in PyCharm with paths with spaces?

Thanks.

EDIT 1
PyCharm dont recognize path with baskslash as valid path either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's known bug http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-8449

Fixed in PyCharm 2.7

Comment: ktisha, I don't want to renew my subscription just to get this bug fixed. I'm a very happy PyCharm 2.6 user. There's no way to fix this in 2.6 or just workaround it?

Comment: I have solved it by creating a symbolic link to the project folder, but without the white spaces. But thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In UNIX you can escape whitespaces with a backslash:

```
/home/paulo/Projetos/repo2/Paulo\ Brito/phl
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaply. Unfortunatelly, Pycharm don't accept this form either. I've already tried that. I'll put this information in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on ubuntu 18.4 LTS pycharm 2019.2.6.
I was trying to create a basic Django new project in folder 'Learing Django api' (my folder name had spaces in it). when I tried to run the server I got a error saying settings module not defined. 
After spending few hours I realized pycharm was creating a seperate folder named 'Learning' in same directory. 
I renamed my folder 'Learing Django api' to 'Learing_Django_api' and it worked. 
I like pycharm but this folder insensitivity is insane.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are taking in the argument with a space in it into a variable, then passing that to something that is seeing two arguments instead of one? If so, "requote" it before passing it along. Will you hit a point where that can't be corrected? If so, maybe the upgrade makes sense.